# Just a regular multiplication

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

**What's the two-word phrase I'm looking for?**

```
tr x 4  = T
re x 6  = C
tr x 8  = O
pe x 12 = D
tr x 20 = I
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two word phrase you are looking for is:

> Platonic solids

Because:

> We have the first two letters of a polygon name - **tr**iangle, **re**ctangle and **pe**ntagon, multiplied by the number of faces, giving the initial letter of the polyhedron (**t**etrahedron, **c**ube, **o**ctagon, **d**odecahedron and **i**cosahedron) that is formed
>
>  And those are the five **regular** polyhedra hinted at by the title.

Comment: rot13(V fhccbfr *fd*hner znl unir orra gbb boivbhf.)